# Not able to login on SO with Blogger account!

Tags: support, stack-overflow, openid, blogger

Basically I noticed it on my own openid implementation first. Then frustrated with yet another openid twist decided to check how it works on SO. And it doesn't for me. As far as I knew blogger openid is just a name of the blog right? Like **http://{blogname}.blogspot.com/**. Well it doesn't let me in. Has blogger discontinued their OpenID support or changed it somehow or is anyone aware of any buzz around it?

I come to a conclusion that openid is a huge mess :(

Answer (score 6):

Actually found the problem - my blog was private. One needs to assign public permissions to a blogger blog to use it as OpenID.

Comment: So perhaps OpenID isn't a huge mess after all?

Comment: thanks for following up jayarjo!

Comment: I think it's a mess. Scarce documentation, standards implementation inconsistency, huge amount of non-obvious caveats and mainly very low respect of the feature from OpenID providers themselves.