# Cannot login to Stack Exchange using Blogger OpenID with custom domain

Tags: support, stack-exchange, login, openid, blogger

I tried to login today using my blogger custom domain account, but I kept getting a 404 error. Here are the steps I tried using both Chrome and a Internet Explorer, both with cache and cookies cleared:

1. Visit any Stackexchange site (SO, DIY, English, etc)
2. Click login button and select More OpenID options
3. Enter my custom domain into the box: http://blog.theg2.net
4. Press login and browser is redirected to the blogger login page (as expected)
5. Login with my blogger credentials
6. Credentials are accepted, but browser is then redirected to a 404 error page.

Depending on the browser I was using the URL that it was directed to would appear different:

IE displayed: https://www.blogger.com/openid-login.do

Chrome displayed (redacted): `https://www.blogger.com/loginz?d=%2Fopenid-confirm.g%3Fidentity%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fblog.theg2.net%252F%26realm%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fenglish.stackexchange.com%252Fusers%252Fauthenticate%252F%26openIdSetupToken%3Doidrp.identity%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fblog.theg2.net%25252F%2526oidrp.return_to%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fenglish.stackexchange.com%25252Fusers%25252Fauthenticate%25252F%25253Fs%25253D8820be50-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-da58db477401%252526dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier%25253Dblog.theg2.net%252526dnoa.op_endpoint%25253Dhttp%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Fwww.blogger.com%2525252Fopenid-server.g%252526dnoa.claimed_id%25253Dhttp%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Fblog.theg2.net%2525252F%2526oidrp.trust_root%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fenglish.stackexchange.com%25252Fusers%25252Fauthenticate%25252F%2526oidrp.assoc_handle%253D&a=ALL&pli=1&auth=DQAAAHwxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx........`

I also noticed that a new login option for "StackExchange Account" was listed. I tried entering in my email account, but it said there was no account associated with it. **Update:** See blog post about new [StackExchange OpenID](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/stack-exchange-is-an-openid-provider/#comment-59113)

**UPDATE**: I was finally able to login by adding a second OpenID to my account (a Google account or [StackExchange ID](https://openid.stackexchange.com)) and then login using that OpenID. It appears either blogger changed their OpenID system and/or StackExchange is no longer comparable with blogger open id accounts. It also works if you login to http://blogger.com before trying to login to a StackExchange site (see answer below). Trying to login to StackExchange first using a blogger OpenID with custom domain still generates a 404 error.

Comment: There's [this old question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56623/not-able-to-login-on-so-with-blogger-account/56624#56624) that says you need a public blogger blog if you're going to use a custom domain - is that the problem?

Comment: I am also having a problem logging in using blogger. I have a public blog and no custom domain (mojoai.blogspot.com). When I enter my details I get directed to a 404 page, but the log in is successful, as I use the same account for Google Mail, and that is subsequently logged in without further action.

Comment: @Rup no... the blog is publicly accessible. It makes it all the way to the blogger login page, it just fails to return after authenticating with blogger. Instead it generates a 404 error message.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What has been working for me so far is to log into Blogger itself in a separate tab, and then come back and log into the StackExchange site. The credentials are cached and it won't send you to the login page, you'll just get logged right in.

Comment: Thanks, that works for me too! Seems like this might be an issue with Blogger's implementation of OpenID. Also FYI if you have Google 2 factor authentication setup on your account you can login to blogger.com using a code from your phone, but when you try to login to the blogger OpenID redirect page from StackExchange it requires you to use a special application specific password.

Comment: Now I can actually log in again! Definitely +1

Comment: This worked for me until just recently, and I finally had to link up my Blogger account with Stack Exchange's OpenID