# Cannot login to Stack Exchange with Blogger OpenID

Tags: support, stack-exchange, openid, blogger

Is the login with a Blogger account still working?

I just used to get an error, but besides that, it used to work fine. Now I cannot login at all (white page with "oops there was an error title").

I have the same problem like in [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56623/not-able-to-login-on-so-with-blogger-account), but I don't have my blog private...

It was tested with Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Comment: What was the error you used to get? If you had been getting an error and now you can't log in at all, there's a pretty good chance that something is broken.

Comment: I used to get a 404 but it was logging me in. Most of the people who were using blogger where having the same issue, but it used to work... now it doesn't.